# Уразливість і Вразливість

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Раніше вважав, що це однакові слова і просто використовуються за зручністю. Але вирішив запитати.

Цікавить саме значення слів *"(у)вразливість безпеки"*, *"(у)вразливість інформаційної безпеки"*. Якщо ж значення однакові, то які правила їх використання?

Answer (score 4):

З СУМ-20

> [ВРА́ЗЛИ́ВІСТЬ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16321&page=541)  (УРА́ЗЛИ́ВІСТЬ), вості, ж. Властивість за знач.
> вра́зли́вий1 1, 2. *О, скільки б я тепер дав за ту юнацьку наївність і
> вразливість* (Ю. Яновський); – *Може, в серці нема тої вразливості,
> тої ніжності, що була...* (О. Гончар).
>
> [ВРА́ЗЛИ́ВИЙ1](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16319&page=541) (УРА́ЗЛИ́ВИЙ), а, е. 1. Який легко й швидко
> піддається зовнішнім подразненням; сприйнятливий, чутливий.
> 2. Який завдає болю, образи 3. Який викликає глибокі почуття; зворушливий. 4. діал. Докучливий, настирливий.

Це однакові слова.

Comment: А в СУМ-11 є відмінність
http://sum.in.ua/s/urazlyvyj
http://sum.in.ua/s/vrazlyvyj

Comment: @KorolenkoS Чесно кажучи не бачу відмінності. Фактично СУМ каже: є два значення, які можна умовно позначити як Вразливий 1 (те саме що Уразливий 2) та Вразливий 2 (те саме що Уразливий 1). Можливо одне із значень частіше використовується починаючи з У-, а інше з В-, але принципово різниці немає. Ось типовий приклад із словника: "**Уразливе** місце — найбільш слабка сторона кого-, чого-небудь. — На жаль, Обручов такий обережний, що важко намацати у нього **вразливе** місце:""

Comment: Або ця стаття із прикладами: "**УРАЗЛИВИЙ** 1 (ВРАЗЛИВИЙ), а, е.
1. Дуже чутливий до дотику, подразнення і т. ін.; болючий. Почав [Павло] перев'язувати Званцева .. Рана була не глибока, але **вразлива**, під самою лопаткою, і боляче озивалася на кожен рух (Василь Кучер, Голод, 1961, 230); 
//  на що. Чутливий до чогось, який легко піддається дії, впливові чого-небудь. Біда була тільки в тому, що та ніжна рожева шкіра [дівочого обличчя] була дуже **вразлива** на веснянки (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 378)."

Comment: І навпаки: "**ВРАЗЛИВИЙ** 1 (УРАЗЛИВИЙ), а, е.
1. Який легко й швидко піддається зовнішнім подразненням; сприйнятливий, чутливий. Він такий чулий до сліз та болю, **уразливий** до безталання та нужди (Панас Мирний, I, 1954, 347); //  Який має підвищену здатність нервово збуджуватися, реагувати на образи. Семен чекав, не тратив надії. Але дедалі неспокій опановував Семеном. Він зробився **уразливим**, нетерплячим (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 117)." Тобто на слово "вразливий" дають приклади із словом "уразливий", а на слово "уразливий" - приклади із словом "вразливий".

Answer (score 0):

Заглянемо спершу в СУМ11. "[Уразливість](http://sum.in.ua/s/urazlyvistj)" та "[вразливість](http://sum.in.ua/s/vrazlyvistj)" там позначаються як синоніми. Однак, якщо ми подивимося слова "уразливий" та "вразливий", то побачимо деякі відмінності:

> Уразливий - слабкий, погано захищений. Наші підрозділи зуміли цілком
>   несподівано заявитися на уразливих флангах німців і навіть у них в
>   тилу.
>
> Уразливе місце (**а не вразливе!**) — найбільш слабка сторона кого-,
>   чого-небудь.

Тобто, коли ми говоримо про "безпеку", то потрібно вживати слова "уразливий" та "вразливий" (див. Вікіпедія [1](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97)) та [2](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)). А також дивимося [переклад](https://translate.academic.ru/vulnerability/en/uk/) схожого "control vulnerability" - "уразливість системи управління".

Однак, інколи ці слова можуть бути синонімами і крім СУМу це підтверджує і [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9).